# Rotate view with active knife tool not possible with Maya settings

Tags: knife-tool

I am using Blender 2.93 with Maya modelling settings (alt + left mouse button for tumbling). It's not possible to rotate the view while using the knife tool. How can I fix this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe assign rotation to alternative key that you can use while using knife? Or using default Blender settings

Comment: I'm not sure you can rotate your view when you activate the knife (K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by reassigning the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> in the *Blender Preferences > Knife Tool Preferences > Panning*.

[image]